# wordpress prevent multiple shortcodes

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I created a wordpress plugin and I added shortcode feature to it. 
but i want to execute only one shortcode and prevent applying of multiple shortcodes if the administrator did so.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find what you need here:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40733/check-for-shortcode-in-post-pages-and-widgets-and-template-files

However please note that if you allow only one shortcode to run, if your client installs a plugin that used shortcodes this will not work.

Why you need this anyway? Maybe we can find a better solution :)

Comment: I created a shortcode that add a calendar plugin to the page, and if the admin add the shortcode more than one time it will produce some errors. i want to apply this technique just on my plugin and my shortcode not on other's ones.

Comment: What error do you get? The solution is to fix those errors not to shut down all the other shortcodes

Comment: I dont want to display more than one calendar inside the same page, that's it :)

Comment: thanks for your respond @GabrielCol. 
I got an idea that worked great for me and did what i wanted exactly. 


    add_filter('the_content','clean_duplicated_smart_calendar');
    
    function clean_duplicated_smart_calendar($content){
        $matches_codes = preg_match("/\[smart_calendar\]/",$content,$matches);
        if(count($matches) > 0){
            $content = preg_replace("/\[smart_calendar\]/","",$content);
            $content = $content.'[smart_calendar]';
        }
        return $content;
    }

this code is working good :)